# What is closure thingy without the final parentheses?

Tags: javascript

What is the difference between a closure and a what-cha-ma-call-it?

I understand that

```
var x = (function(){})();
```

x gets assign a closure.  Nothing special here.

```
var y = (function(arg1){
            const _hello = ()=>{ return' world'}
           return {
                 hello:_hello
             }
       });
```

What is y? what-cha-ma-call-it ?

```
var x = y(arg)
```

And what is x now? Still a closure?

Comment: `Closure` is a concept where you can access variables in parent scope from children scope. It has nothing to do with IIFEs. As to answer your question, *What is y?*, its a function. When you put code inside `()` it creates an expression and execute it. So your `y` will hold output of this expression a.k.a, anonymous function.

Comment: `x` is not generally a closure, it is whatever the function returns (in the first case, `undefined`; in the second case, an object - which does contain a closure in its `hello` property). `y` is a closure (because JavaScript treats any function as a closure, even if over nothing).

Comment: There both IFFE's.  The only difference is what they return.  The first will return the result of the function.  The send will return an object with a function property called hello, that has a closure to arg1.

Comment: @Keith Second one is missing calling parenthesis... So its just an expression

Comment: @Keith: `var y = ...` is not an IIFE, just a FE.

Answer (score 0):

`(function(){})()` will execute the function, try `(function(){console.log(0)})()`

and try `(function(item){console.log(item)})(0)`

y will be a function.

`x = {"hello": ()=>{ return' world'}}`